# Firebase - Getting a Child Value

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a child value within Firebase.

This is the HTML:

```
  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider color="light">We Need</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let list of lists" (click)="unlist()">{{list?.foodname}}</ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
```

Arrays were declared in the TS here:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  foods;
  lists;
  startAt = new Subject()
  endAt = new Subject()
```

The function in the TS is:

```
  unlist() {
    firebase.database().ref('foods').child()
            .update({ state: "unlisted" });
  }
```

This is the structure of my database:

```
{
  "foods" : {
    "foodID1" : {
      "category" : "Produce",
      "foodname" : "Apples",
      "state" : "listed"
    },
    "foodID2" : {
      "category" : "Dairy",
      "foodname" : "Cheese",
      "state" : "listed"
    },
    "foodID3" : {
      "foodname" : "Eggs",
      "state" : "unlisted"
    },
    "foodID4" : {
      "category" : "Dairy",
      "foodname" : "Milk",
      "state" : "unlisted"
    },
    "foodID5" : {
      "category" : "Produce",
      "foodname" : "Onions",
      "state" : "unlisted"
    }
  }
}
```

Right now, firing this function adds the child of "state" to "foods" rather than changing the pre-existing state.

How can I get the value of the child without manually entering "FoodID1", "FoodID2", and so on?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the post has been updated.

Comment: The state of what food are you trying to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the onClick event to `(click)="unlist(list)"` and changing the function to:

```
unlist(list) {
    firebase.database().ref('foods').child(list.$key)
          .update({ state: "unlisted" });}
```